# How do you split up an AJAX response so you don't have to make several requests?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I couldn't think of a better title, but here is the explanation:

I am making an ajax request that looks like this:

```
...
xmlhttp.send("data1=" + $data);
...

document.getElementById("data1display").innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText;
...
```

Now the page has developed and I want to send another variable, data2 to the same php page for processing.

I realise I can add data to xmlhttp.send like `"data1=" + $data + "data2=" + $data2`

But! How do I split the response to update two separate elements? (data1display and data2display).

the code that builds the response:

```
if ( isset( $_POST["data1"] ) ) 

 die($object->function()); //returns html to fill the specified element.
```

Comment: both get and post would allow multiple variables

Comment: You missed the problem Dagon, it is the splitting up of the response that I don't know how to do.

Comment: Can we see the code that builds the response?

Comment: @Chris Hanson Sure, added to the original post.

Comment: what does the response look like when you ask for multiple objects?

Comment: It just returns mixed HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your php processing page sends back JSON instead of html, you could expect the following:

```
{
    "data1display": "<div>whatever</div>",
    "data2display": "<div>something</div>"
}
```

and then in your js success callback, you could do something like:

```
var targetIdArray = ["data1display", "data2display"];
var responseJSON = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
for (var i = 0; i < targetIdArray.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(targetIdArray[i]).innerHTML= responseJSON[targetIdArray[i]];
}
```

If you want to stick with html in the response, you can add a class or ID to each part of the response and grab the correct nodes from the response using regular old jQuery selectors.

Eventually, you may want to change your frontend framework though, so it may be even better to just pass back the data you want to present and let the client render it. This would mean not passing html back to the client at all and instead using some templating solution like [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

```
{
    "data1display": "whatever",
    "data2display": "something"
}
```

you could then make a couple of small templates like:

```
<div>{{ content }}</div>
```

and render them in the client.

Comment: I have updated my post with the mechanism I am delivering the post reply, can you elaborate in the context of how to form the json based on that please?

Comment: Sorry, I'm useless with php.

Comment: Ok, well thanks for the info, I think I need to learn JSON. I will update the tick when its avaialble

Answer (score 0):

Can you not putan if statement and say if this request is set then do

document.getElementById("data1display").innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText;

Else do this

document.getElementById("data2").innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText;

Just add if statements into your ajax

Comment: No you have missed the problem